# Wordpress: Save custom plugin options from backend

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I'm developing a plugin that will pull data from a third party API. The user user inputs a number of options in a normal settings form for the plugin (used Reduz Framework - that uses WP Settings API).

The user provided options will then be used to generate a request to the third party API.

Now to my problem / question: How can I store the data that's returned from that API? Is there a built in way to do this in Wordpress - or will I have to install a database table of my own? Seems to be a bit overkill... Is there any way to "hack" in to the Settings API and set custom settings without having to display them in a form on front end?

Thank you - and happy holidays to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is actually just store the data from the remote API request, rather than "options". If you don't want to create a table for them, I can think of three simple approaches.

**[Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API)**

Save the data returned from the API as [transients](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_transient), i.e. temporary cached data. This is generally good for data that's going to expire anyway and thus will need to be refreshed. Set an expiry time! Even if you want to hang onto the data "for ever", set an expiry time or the data will be autoloaded on every page load and thus consume memory even if you don't need them. You can then easily retrieve them with [get_transient](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_transient); if expired, you'll get `false` and that is your trigger to make your API call again.

NB: on hosts with memcached or other object caches, there's a good chance that your transients will be pushed out of the object cache sooner than you intend, thus forcing your plugin to retrieve the data again from the API. Transients really are about caching, not "data storage" *per se*.

**[Options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)**

Save your data as custom options using [add_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) -- and specify autoload="no" so that they don't fill up script memory when they aren't needed! Beware the [update_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) will add the data with autoload="yes" if it doesn't already exist, so I recommend you [delete](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_option) and then add rather than update. You can then [retrieve](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) your data easily.

**[Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types)**

You can easily store your data in the `wp_posts` table by registering a custom post type, and then you can use [wp_insert](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) to save them and the usual WordPress [post queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to retrieve them. Great for long-term data that you want to hang onto. You can make use of the `post_title`, `post_content`, `post_excerpt` and other standard post fields to store some of your data, and if you need more, you can [add post meta fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta).

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer! I think I'm gonna go with transients since I will need to load the API response every 24-48 hours or so. It also seems to be the easiest solution.